# Solaris + run my script after Solaris boot/reboot

Tags: solaris

I have Solaris machine ( Solaris installed on Netra-T2000 HW , Solaris version – 5.10 )

I write the script - update_after_solaris_already_boot.ksh

This script will update automatically some files/configuration after Solaris completely finished the boot process

My question where or on which file I need to locate my script - update_after_solaris_already_boot.ksh ,

in order to run my script only after Solaris is up ( after boot )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the script in /etc/init.d 
then `ln -s /etc/init.d/<filename> /etc/rc3.d/S<XX><filename>` where XX is between 01-99.
S99 will be the last script run during boot.

for more info http://www.freeos.com/articles/3243 or search  `system V boot` in google